# Login and password variables

Tags: python, authentication, variables, passwords, replit

Good afternoon! I was told to do login and password variables with python on **repl.it**.

The program should check them for these values:

1. The password must consist of numbers and letters, with a minimum length of 8 characters
2. Login must be 5 characters or more

Else, program must print Error

A big request to do everything on a **beginner's level, without using libraries or other**

**Thank you!**

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Comment: @PCM  The main problem is that the last time I was coding on python was a long time ago, and I remember half of it, but in this particular task I can't figure out how to set the character boundaries and the number of characters

Comment: @PCM As far as I understand, you need to create a variable, e.g. x
This variable should be given a command, for example int(input("Login: "))
But how to calculate the number of characters entered by the user, that's the question

Comment: Look at my answer

Comment: @PCM I don't see any answer.
Maybe I don't know where to find it

Comment: I will write it i meant

Comment: I will just give you an example. You can modify it to your use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just giving you an example.
Take x as login variable and y as password login for this eg. -

```
x = input('Enter Username ')

if len(x) >= 5:
    y = input('Enter Password ')
    if y.isalpha() == True or y.isdigit() == True:
        print('Password must contain both Letters and Numbers')

    else:
        if len(y) >= 8:

            print('Password Accepted')

        else:
            print('Password must be 8 or more letters')

else:
    print('Username must be 5 or more letters')
```

Comment: Use this logic for your repl.it. I am not too good at repl.it though

Comment: Thank you! I have one question
What does this line do? if y.isalpha() == True or y.isdigit() == True:

Comment: `y.isalpha == true` will be true when the input will only have letters

Comment: `y.isdigit() == true` will be true when the input will only have numbers

Comment: So when they become true, the `'Password must contain both Letters and Numbers'` will run

Comment: but if the password kept has both numbers and letters, it will continue

Comment: You can also use while loop so that the username and password is asked again and again unless they give accepted values